# Download an EXE file using Window Application

Tags: window, download

I write a code to check an update for my application which is working fine.

Now what i wants to do is, I have an URL of my update. I wants to save that file in my temp folder silently without user notification(means once user click on "Yes" button of an Update dialog) and then install that file in machine.

I tried a way using "Process.Start" but it opens IE in user's machine and then download the file which i don't want.

Comment: Search through the win32 api here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx. More specifically: WinINet

Comment: `Process.Start` suggests C#, which has a nicer (IMO) way of downloading files than WinInet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to programatically download the file.
Use WebRequest and WebResponse, open a stream and save it to a file.

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("YOUR URL");
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
Stream s = resp.GetResponseStream();
// Now save this stream to a file
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for reply. Its executing without an error. But it's not start downloading the Setup file..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java, you could use the apache commons httpclient library to download the file.